# Syncing up between leader & follower ADX cluster

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there a continuous low latency 'sync up' process going on between a leader & follower cluster so that the follower databases are up date to date with the copy stored in the leader cluster? Basically trying to understand if the follower maintains its own read only copy (not referring to follower cache) of the follower databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follower cluster periodically synchronizes to changes in the database(s) it follows, so it has some data lag with respect to the leader cluster.

- The lag could vary between a few seconds to a few minutes, depending on the overall size of the followed database(s) metadata.

Once the follower cluster becomes aware of these changes in metadata (data and/or schema objects [e.g. tables] get added/removed) - there's a background process that 'warms' the relevant data artifacts from the leader's persistent storage to the SSD of the follower's nodes.

- Data is cached (according to the effective caching policy) on the nodes of the leader and on the nodes of the follower, but is persisted only in the leader's persistent storage.

Comment: Is it only happening for cache? Lets assume we alter follower cache to absolute minimum 1min -- so I think it won't sync up for any data outside that 1 min window then.

Comment: Data that isn't supposed to be cached on the follower, according to the effective caching policy - will not be cached on the follower's nodes. BTW, the absolute minimum is not 1min, it is 0.

Comment: How do I specify 0 caching for a table? If I delete cache policy for a table then the database cache policy will take precedence which in my case is 30 days, so considering that how I I explicitly specify 0 caching for my table?

Comment: just like specifying any other time period for caching: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/cache-policy#altering-the-cache-policy. 
`.alter table T policy caching hot = 0s`